# How to deduce number of unordered distinct pairs using set operations and bijections

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

[image]

In (b) of the example, we are ask to calculate the number of ordered pairs of distinct positive integers. I like the first method's answer (using bijections, set operations) because it clearly shows how the answer was arrived at.

The last paragraph of the example shows how to deduce the number of unordered distinct pairs. I don't understand at all the process used (I am familiar with this line of reasoning which I learned back in high school but this is just rote memorization to me).

How do I construct an argument to show the number of unordered distinct pairs using the first method of the answer to part (b)?

Comment: The way to "reduce" the 72 *ordered pairs* to the $72/2=36$ *unordered pairs* is simply to note that the two ordered pairs $(n,m)$ and $(m,n)$ are the same unoredered one, i.e. the two-elements set : $\{ n, m \}$.

Comment: I don't know how to express that idea mathematically. Could you please show me how?

Comment: It is simply a problem of [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) : "In mathematics, a *combination* is a way of selecting members from a grouping, such that the order of selection does not matter. In smaller cases it is possible to count the number of combinations. For example given three fruits, say an apple, an orange and a pear, there are three combinations of two that can be drawn from this set: an apple and a pear; an apple and an orange; or a pear and an orange." 1/2

Comment: In your case, you have $9$ objects grouped into couples; thus the number is $n!/[k!(n-k)!]$, with $n=9$ and $k=2$ which amount to : $(9 \times 8)/2 = 72/2 = 36$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visually: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\color{blue}{1,1} & 2,1 & \cdots & 8,1 & 9,1 
\\ 1,2 & \color{blue}{2,2} & \cdots & 8,2 & 9,2 
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \color{blue}{\ddots} & \vdots & \vdots 
\\ 1,8 & 2,8 & \cdots & \color{blue}{8,8} & 9,8
\\ 1,9 & 2,9 & \cdots & 8,9 & \color{blue}{9,9} \end{bmatrix}$$

$\mathbb{N}_9\times \mathbb{N}_9$ is a $9\times 9$ grid of coordinate pairs.   $\Delta \mathbb{N}_9$, the set of equal pairs, is the diagonal; shown in blue.   So the remainder of the grid is the set of ordered unequal pairs, which is $\mathbb{N}_9\times \mathbb{N}_9-\Delta \mathbb{N}_9$.

Notice how the grid is mirror symmetrical about the diagonal.   Each pair on the upper right triangle has a corresponding pair in the lower left triangle, which has the same members but reversed order.   Thus the number of unordered unequal pairs is:
$$\frac{|\mathbb{N}_9\times \mathbb{N}_9-\Delta \mathbb{N}_9|}{2} = \frac{9\times 9 - 9}{2} = \frac{9\times 8}{2}$$

---

Now this reasoning can be extended to triplets or more, but becomes harder to visualise.

The set of triplets would be $\mathbb{N}_9\times \mathbb{N}_9\times\mathbb{N}_9$, a cube.   There are **three** diagonal planes in the cube, which each contain at least a pair of equal numbers (and one other). These are $\mathbb{N}_9\times \Delta \mathbb{N}_9$.  And these three planes all intersect in the diagonal line, $\Delta^2 \mathbb{N}_9$.

The remainder of the cube is the set of ordered unequal pairs.  To count this we have to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion.  Since if we exclude the three diagonal planes we will have excluded the diagonal line three times, then we need to include it again three times.  Thus the count is $|\mathbb{N}_9\times\mathbb{N}_9\times\mathbb{N}_9|-3|\mathbb{N}_9\times\Delta\mathbb{N}_9|+3|\Delta^2\mathbb{N}_9|$, the number of ordered mutually-unequal triplets.

We can observe that the cube has been cut by the diagonal planes into six symmetric pyramids.  So the number of *unordered* mutually-unequal triplets is one sixth of that.

$$\frac{|\mathbb{N}_9\times\mathbb{N}_9\times\mathbb{N}_9|-3|\mathbb{N}_9\times\Delta\mathbb{N}_9|+3|\Delta^2\mathbb{N}_9|}{6}=\frac{9\times 9\times 9 - 3\times(9\times 9) + 3 \times 9}{6}=\frac{9\times 8 \times 7}{3\times 2\color{gray}{\times 1}}$$

---

While it is significantly harder to visualise, the number of unordered mutually-unequal quadruplets can be determined the same way, from the diagonal cubes, planes, and lines of a 4-dimensional hypercube:

It is *much* easier, however, to simply notice the pattern which has formed, and if you've been already introduced to the factorial notation, this is:
$$\frac{9\times 8\times 7\times 6}{4\times 3\times 2\color{gray}{\times 1}} = \frac{9!}{4!5!}$$